# Fonts in Matplotlibrc

Tags: python, debugging, matplotlib, plot, fonts

I would appreciate any insights into an issue I'm having.

I have recently downloaded python 3 onto my MacBook Pro. I have a sample python script in which I am plotting a few curves, and try to run this script using python 3 from the terminal command line. Before running the script from the command line, I have made some changes to the `matplotlibrc` file which controls the look of plots.

Specifically, I've set the `font.family` choice in the `matplotlibrc` file to `sans-serif` by writing `font.family : sans-serif`. The reason I have this is because I would like the Avant Garde font, so in the file I have also `font.sans-serif : Avant Garde`.

However, when I run the script from the terminal command line using `python3 script.py` I get the following error message:

```
findfont: Font family ['sans-serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
findfont: Font family ['sans-serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
findfont: Font family ['sans'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
findfont: Font family ['sans'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
findfont: Font family ['sans'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
```

So the resulting plot does not display words in the sans-serif, Avant Garde font.

I've tried using `pip3 install fonts` in the terminal command line, but this doesn't help.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You need to use the exact name of the font. So in my case I have `"AvantGarde Bk BT"` and that works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The issue is that the error is happening before the point where I call Avant Garde; it is happening where the sans-serif font family is set. I tried making your suggested change, and I still get the same errors as above.

Comment: You do not call a font. The warning means that the font you specified is not available. So either it has a different name, or you don't have it installed.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to practically resolve the error statements I am seeing?

Comment: Yes, practically, you need to find out the font name of the Avant Garde font you would like to use. Probably right clicking on the font in your system will help you do that.

Comment: See below, this still does not work.

Comment: The font name is not the file name. For example, on my system the file name is `AvantGarde_Bk_BT_Demi.ttf`, but the font's name  is `"AvantGarde Bk BT"` as stated in the first comment.

Comment: I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: I told you how to solve it. You need to find the file in one of your font folders and get the font name from that file, e.g. via the properties context menu. Did you try that?

Comment: I've now just downloaded the Anaconda Distribution to see if using python from this would work. I've modified the matplotlibrc file of anaconda3. When I run my script using Spyder, I get the same error message: `findfont: Font family ['sans-serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.`

Comment: Which font name did you use?

Comment: I can't access the context menu for the `AVANTN.TTF` font in ~/Library/Fonts/ because the Library directory doesn't show in the Finder. I can only access this folder through the terminal.

Comment: For the `AVANTN.TTF`, I tried several. I tried `font.sans-serif : Avant Garde Normal`, `font.sans-serif : AVANTN`, `font.sans-serif : Avant N`, and `font.sans-serif : Avant Garde N`.

Comment: I don't have a Mac. But from [pictures on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=macos+fonts&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDt7uQ87LkAhXH-qQKHR5VBMAQ_AUIESgB&biw=1840&bih=916) it should be possible.

Comment: I looked up a way on google. I went to ~/Library/Fonts/ by typing "open `pwd`" in a terminal. The context menu looks like this: https://ibb.co/dMYSx32 . So I put in `font.sans-serif : Avant Garde Normal` into the matplotlibrc file, according to the full name shown in the context menu. Even with this, I am getting the same error message, which is: `findfont: Font family ['sans-serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans`, and the plot does not have text written in Avant Garde font.

Comment: I am willing to add another 50 to the current bounty of 50, to make 100, if someone may have the answer to this issue.

Comment: Stay calm. Noone will gain more knowledge about your problem even if you add a million points to it. You have now found out the font name. Next steps: What does `import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.rcParams["font.sans-serif"])` print? What happens if you create a script with the following content `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcParams["font.sans-serif"] = "Avant Garde Normal"; plt.text(.5, .5, "Test"); plt.show()`?

Comment: Thank you for your help. `import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.rcParams["font.sans-serif"])` gives `['Avant Garde Normal']`. The second script gives the plot shown here: https://ibb.co/Wx0C7QS . As you can see, the 'Test' in the plot's centre is not in Avant Garde font, and I am also still getting the same error message from the terminal saying `findfont: Font family ['sans-serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans`.

Comment: Ok, try this: `import matplotlib.font_manager;
fp = matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(fname=r"C:\windows\fonts\AvantGarde_Bk_BT_Demi.ttf");
print(fp.get_name())` where you need to replace the path with the absolute path to the `AVANTN.TTF` on your system. The output should be `Avant Garde Normal`, but if it isn't, that would explain everything.

Comment: Thank you for this insightful comment. It turns out the output from `import matplotlib.font_manager; fp = matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(fname=r"C:\windows\fonts\AvantGarde_Bk_BT_Demi.ttf"); print(fp.get_name())` is `AvantGarde Normal`, not `Avant Garde Normal`, even though the context menu shows the full name to be the latter. I was using the latter, but now that I erased the space between `Avant` and `Garde`, it works. I appreciate your help with this. So that I can send you the 50-point bounty, please could you write a short answer below (as I cannot through these comments)?

Comment: Although Avant Garde is now generally working, I just noticed one last thing now. See the following plot: https://ibb.co/xmNh228 . You can see that all looks good, but the bottom axis is in log scale. The labels are supposed to show the numbers 'two times ten to the the zero', 'four times ten to the zero', etc. For some reason the \times sign gets replaced by a strange symbol. When I used Avant Garde in the past with matplotlib, I never got this problem when using scientific notation. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: Looking at the character table [here](http://www.eaglefonts.com/avant-garde-normal-ttf-8123.htm) shows indeed this [cyrilic symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLA2o.png) for the times sign. It would hence make sense to use a different font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the extensive comments below the question:

It is important to use the *exact* name of the font when specifying which font to use via the rcParams. In this concrete case, the problem is that even though the font name is shown as `Avant Garde Normal` in the system context menu, it's real name is `AvantGarde Normal` (without the first blank).

This can be found out if the file name of the font is known. In this case

```
import matplotlib.font_manager
fp = matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(fname=r"Absolute\Path\to\fonts\AVANTN.TTF")
print(fp.get_name())
```

Hence in the rc parameter file one needs to specify

```
font.sans-serif : AvantGarde Normal
```

Answer (score 1):

could you possibly check if matplotlib knows you font exists with these lines

```
import matplotlib.font_manager
matplotlib.font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None, fontext='ttf')
```

if the desired font does not show up you have to add it to ~/Library/Fonts/

note: it has to be a ttf file

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried this, and the only Avant Garde font which I see in ~/Library/Fonts/ is `AVANTN.ttf` . So I changed `font.sans-serif : Avant Garde` in the `matplotlibrc` file to `font.sans-serif : AVANTN`, but I am still getting the same error message, which is: `findfont: Font family ['sans-serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans`.